# Changing build flags and recompiling

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make file with a number of phony targets, they all compile the same code just with different compilation flags.

```
EXECUTABLE=ecis

#debug build
.PHONY: debug
debug: FLAGS=-g
debug: $(EXECUTABLE)

#No optimization
.PHONY: opt0
opt0: FLAGS=
opt0: $(EXECUTABLE)

#level 1 optimization
.PHONY: opt1
opt1: FLAGS=-O1
opt1: $(EXECUTABLE)

#level 2 optimization
.PHONY: opt2
opt2: FLAGS=-O2
opt2: $(EXECUTABLE)

...

$(EXECUTABLE):$(FORTRAN_OBJECTS) $(CPP_OBJECTS)
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS) $(FORTRAN_OBJECTS) $(CPP_OBJECTS) -lgfortran -o $@
...
```

When I first run the makefile with one build `make opt2` option it runs just fine.
If I subsequently want to run make with another build option say `make debug` it claims that the target is up to date. I understand why it is doing this, make doesn't realize that the flags changed and so as far as make is concerned nothing has changed if the files haven't changed.

That said, is there an easy way around it other than calling `make cleanall` (which deletes the .o files and the executable)? Is there some way for make to recognize the different flags as changing the compilation? Are there any other paths to have it "do the right thing"?

Comment: Not an easy way, no.  There are ways to do it.  For example you can write the flags to a file then make that file a prerequisite of all your compile rules.  The recipe for the file should test to see if the flags are the same and if so, it _must not change the modification time_ of the file.  If the mod time is not changed, make will assume the file is not updated and won't consider targets depending on it to be out of date.  If the flags are different it should overwrite the file with the new flags.

Comment: @MadScientist: I editted the question to also ask if there is any other way to make it "do the right thing", that way there is some leeway for solutions. Thanks for an initial idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that should work:

```
.compile_flags: Makefile
        [ "`cat $@`" = '$(FLAGS)' ] || echo '$(FLAGS)' > $@

$(FORTRAN_OBJECTS) $(CPP_OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE): .compile_flags
```

An alternative is to generate the object files and executable into a separate subdirectory for each different base target.  Then they won't overlap.  This has the added benefit that you don't have to recompile the world for each type of build (only since the last time you did that build).  But it uses more disk space and may cause other issues if you have other parts of the system expecting things to live where they do now.

To put things in other directories can't be done with target-specific variables.  The simplest way to do it is to use one instance of recursive make instead, like this:

```
EXECUTABLE=ecis

#debug build
.PHONY: debug
debug: FLAGS=-g

#No optimization
.PHONY: opt0
opt0: FLAGS=

#level 1 optimization
.PHONY: opt1
opt1: FLAGS=-O1

#level 2 optimization
.PHONY: opt2
opt2: FLAGS=-O2

debug opt0 opt1 opt2:
        $(MAKE) OUTDIR=obj_$@ FLAGS=$(FLAGS) obj_$@/$(EXECUTABLE)
...
FORTRAN_OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/,$(FORTRAN_OBJECTS))
CPP_OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/,$(CPP_OBJECTS))

$(OUTDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE):$(FORTRAN_OBJECTS) $(CPP_OBJECTS)
    $(CPP) $(FLAGS) $(FORTRAN_OBJECTS) $(CPP_OBJECTS) -lgfortran -o $@
...
```

And, you'll have to create pattern rules for your object files like:

```
$(OUTDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
        ...
```

and ditto for FORTRAN.

Comment: Disk space isn't a problem, and nothing other than build depends on the location of the .o files so the second method you suggest is probably the better one. Should I set a destination folder in my .PHONYs as I do the flags and then have my rules look like $(DESTINATION)/fileName.o:...   ?

Comment: You can't set that using target-specific variables.  Those variables are only in effect for the recipe of the build, they can't modify the target or the prerequisite.  There are lots of discussions on stackoverflow and other places of how to put object files in different directories.  I'll update the answer with one simple option.

Comment: Your method worked very well. The only thing I had to add was -mkdir -p obj_$@ above the recursive call to ensure that the output directory exists. A little thinking let me get the clean and cleanall targets working correctly too. Thanks again!

Comment: I disagree.  Recursive make is a powerful tool and can be very useful: it can greatly simplify some types of operations.  Just like `goto`, we shouldn't discard useful facilities only because someone once published a whitepaper.  None of the issues with recursive make described in Miller's paper apply in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're limited to GNU make itself, you'll have trouble achieving your goal.  As @MadScientist suggested, you can basically get what you want with some shenanigans.  John Graham-Cumming wrote up a good explanation in his old "Ask Mr. Make" column:  [Rebuilding when CPPFLAGS Changes](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/rebuilding-when-cppflags-changes).

If you can use other make implementations, you might check out [Electric Make](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator.php), a reimplementation of GNU make designed for performance and reliability.  It includes a feature called "ledger" which provides precisely this functionality.

*Disclaimer: I'm the architect and lead developer of Electric Make*

Comment: Thanks for the link to the "Ask Mr. Make" article. Electric Make is interesting looking but right now I am looking to keep this project and its dependencies open source. The reason for this is that I want to get a paper in Nuclear Instruments and Methods A out of this project and other scientists might get annoyed / not use the code if they have to use something other than commonly available on linux system tools. Thanks for your input though.